# Model in rjags for sum to zero constraints

Tags: r, winbugs

I am trying to fit an ANOVA model into rjags. The model is like this

```
for (r in 1:nE){
  for ( j in 1:nP){
    for ( i in 1:nA){
      logit(p[i,j,r]) <- mu[r] + theta[i,r] + varphi[j,r] + psi[(nA-i)+j,r]
    }
  }
}
```

And I need to fit in the constraints that

```
for (r in 1:nE){
  theta[nA,r] <- 0 - sum(theta[1:(nA-1), r])
  varphi[nP,r] <- 0 - sum(varphi[1:(nP-1), r])
  psi[nK,r] <- 0 - sum(psi[1:(nK-1), r])
}
```

which is the sum to zero constraints for this model. However, rjags gives me the message

```
"Compilation error on line 14. Attempt to redefine node varphi[16,1]"
```

If I delete the constraint part, the model compiled just fine but will not converge.  In BUGS, the model is accepted.

How can I implement these constraints in rjags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Make *new* zero sum variables (don't redefine the old ones) and monitor them instead.
2. Reparameterize the model to use a corner constraint rather than summing to zero.

1 is the better option since the new variables will probably converge faster.  See [Ntzoufras' book, (ch.5)](http://zoe.bme.gatech.edu/~bv20/bmed2803/Bank72/chapter05.pdf), sec. 5.4.2 for a discussion and also the relevant bugs code.  This *should* also work for jags, although I haven't checked.